# How to get first match combo with value 1 and rest same match combo value as 0 using select

Tags: sql

select * from tableInfo will get below data

[image: Table: col1]

Can you help with the query to get first match combo with value 1 and rest same match combo value as 0 as shown below

[image]

Comment: 1. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). 2. [edit] your question and add tag of dbms being used.

Comment: By dbms i mean something like MySQL OR Oracle OR PostgreSQL.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `row_number()` to give row number to each row starting from 1

```
with cte as (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, col3) as rn
  from mytable
)
select col1, col2, col3, case when rn = 1 then 1 else 0 end as combo
from cte
```

Comment: It works in mysql but not in sqlite as row_number(), over functions are not supported in sqlite 3.1..0. version. Can you also help with sqlite query?

Answer (score 2):

You can use lag function to get previous row and compare with current record,

```
   SELECT 
col1,col2, col3
case when lag(col2) over (partition by col2 order by col2) = col2 then 0 else 1 end rrno
FROM tableInfo
```